# Improve Speed of Matrix Multiplication by Taking Advantage of GPUArray

Tags: matlab

I want to improve the speed of the multiplication of matrix `A` (*m*-by-*n*) and vector `x` (*n*-by-*1*)  using GPUArray. Using:

```
gpuA = gpuArray(A);
gpux = gpuArray(x);
gpuC = gpuA * gpux
C = gather(gpuC)
```

didn't give me the needed improvement in speed

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use `arrayfun`? What sort of multiplication are you trying to do? element-wise per column? If so then use `bsxfun(@times, A, x)`. If you want just regular matrix multiplication you can use `A*x`

Comment: @Dan I want to do the normal matrix multiplication but in a gpuArray. I have read somewhere that using custom functions like arrayfun is faster than the normal A*x when using gpuArray. Is this accurate?

Comment: Then please edit your question and title to reflect that you are trying to improve the speed of regular matrix multiplication by taking advantage of a GPU array

Comment: @Dan I have done that. Do you have any suggestions I can implement to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to first use gpuArray on your matrix i.e gpuArray(A) to transform your matrix into a GPU Array before applying the arrayfun.

Comment: Now that you've changed your question, this really depends on your GPU compared to your CPU, a lot of gaming GPUs are not designed for fast computation. You could try to use this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34080-gpubench to see how much advantage your GPU can help you achieve

Comment: It could also depend on the sizes of the matrices and the number of cores etc etc. Also, is using `sparse` matrices an option for you?

Comment: Thanks @GameOfThrows I used it. But when trying to multiply the matrix and vector with arrayfun, I get the error: 
"Non-singleton dimensions of input arrays must match each other." I need to get the matrix and vector to be the same size and still achieve the matrix multiplication I want. Maybe by filling other columns of x with zeros

Comment: Yes, @Dan sparse matrix is an option I can use. How can I apply it please?

Comment: @Amanda if you have a lot of `0`s in your matrix then read http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html

Comment: Using double precision instead of single precision is also a factor. If your results are not too sensitive to it, you might want to use single precision.